# MongoDB returning exit code 49

Tags: mongodb, exit-code

I installed mongodb and then I created a service to run it.
Starting the service works without problem but while trying to shutdown it, I get an error code by windows. I checked the log file and this is what I get:

`2017-02-23T08:36:51.518+0100 I CONTROL [serviceStopWorker] shutting down with code:49`
[image]

(Translation)
Error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly

**Service path:**

`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.cfg" --service`

**mongodb.cfg**

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "C:\\data\\log\\mongod.log"
storage:
    dbPath: "C:\\data\\db"
```

I tried to find the error codes but it doesn't appear.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/

The only reference I could find is this. A test with questions/answers about exit codes. (Question #7)

http://www.sanfoundry.com/mongodb-questions-answers-exit-codes-statutes/

```
7. 49 code is returned by mongod from _________ Service control Manager.
a) Linux
b) Windows
c) Ubuntu
d) All of the mentioned
View Answer

Answer:a
Explanation:Custom read preferences and write concerns evaluate tags sets in different ways.
```

But I am on a Windows 7 machine. So that's quite odd.

***Windows 7 x64 SP1***

***MongoDB 3.4.2***

Any idea?

***LOG***

> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.484+0100 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17856 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db 64-bit host=FRAmdsWS430
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.485+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.486+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.486+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.486+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.486+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.486+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.cfg", service: true, storage: { dbPath: "C:\data\db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "C:\data\log\mongod.log" } }
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.488+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.497+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\data\db\journal
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.497+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.636+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.636+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.693+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.693+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.693+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.693+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.938+0100 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'Das angegebene Objekt wurde nicht auf dem Computer gefunden.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.938+0100 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.940+0100 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:48.940+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Service running
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.412+0100 I CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] got SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP request from Windows Service Control Manager, will terminate after current cmd ends
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.412+0100 I NETWORK  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.412+0100 I NETWORK  [serviceShutdown] closing listening socket: 456
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.413+0100 I NETWORK  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.413+0100 I FTDC     [serviceShutdown] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.413+0100 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.413+0100 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: final commit...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.438+0100 I JOURNAL  [serviceShutdown] journalCleanup...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.439+0100 I JOURNAL  [serviceShutdown] removeJournalFiles
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.439+0100 I JOURNAL  [serviceShutdown] old journal file will be removed: C:\data\db\journal\j._0
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.439+0100 I JOURNAL  [serviceShutdown] Terminating durability thread ...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.516+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.516+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.516+0100 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: closing all files...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.518+0100 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] closeAllFiles() finished
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.518+0100 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: removing fs lock...
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.518+0100 I CONTROL  [serviceShutdown] now exiting
>
> 2017-02-23T08:36:51.518+0100 I CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] shutting down with code:49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug introduced in MongoDB version 3.4.2. Check out https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6065